# MAUI: RaiseChild property is not found for Grid

Tags: maui

I have grid with 2 child frames like below:

```
<Grid
    x:Name="toplayout_grid">

    <Frame
        x:Name="details_frame">
        
    </Frame>

    <Frame
        x:Name="comment_frame">

    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

I need to highlight the selected frame on top and fade the other frame. I used `toplayout_grid.RaiseChild(details_frame);` in xamarin forms and it was working fine. But in MAUI `RaiseChild` is not available. Is there any equivalent property for achieving that?

**Update**

I have 2 frames inside a grid and when I choose one frame it will highlight and when choose the other one it will highlight and the other one will be in below of that.

Please check the below screenshot: When choose comments frame it is showing on top of the details frame, but when I tap Details it is not showing top of the comments frame due to the lack of RaiseChild, can you suggest any alternative solution for this?

[image]

**My current code:**

```
<Grid
    x:Name="toplayout_grid"
    Margin="0,5,0,0"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="53*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="47*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Frame
        x:Name="details_frame"
        TranslationX="18"
        Grid.Column="0"
        CornerRadius="{OnIdiom Phone=20, Tablet=30}"
        Padding="0"
        HasShadow="False">

        <Label
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Details"
            TextColor="White">
            <Label.FontSize>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                    <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>27</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                </OnIdiom>
            </Label.FontSize>
        </Label>
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="DetailsTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    </Frame>

    <Frame
        x:Name="comment_frame"
        TranslationX="-18"
        HasShadow="False"
        Padding="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        CornerRadius="{OnIdiom Phone=20, Tablet=30}">

        <Label
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Comments"
            TextColor="White">
            <Label.FontSize>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                    <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>27</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                </OnIdiom>
            </Label.FontSize>
        </Label>
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="CommentsTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    </Frame>
</Grid>


//Code behind
//Initial color and RaiseChild section
toplayout_grid.RaiseChild(details_frame);
details_frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#939393");
comment_frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#c2c2c2");  

private void DetailsTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toplayout_grid.RaiseChild(details_frame);
    details_frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#939393");
    comment_frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#c2c2c2");
}

private void CommentsTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toplayout_grid.RaiseChild(comment_frame);
    comment_frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#939393");
    details_frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#c2c2c2");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin's [Layout.RaiseChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout.raisechild?view=xamarin-forms) was replaced by the [IView.ZIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.iview.zindex?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-iview-zindex) property in Maui.

By setting the ZIndex on your Frames you can control their Z order: higher z-indexes will draw over lower z-indexes.

Here's a quick function to swap the Z order of two Views. You'll need to make sure that they start out with different ZIndices. You could also swap the colours similarly rather than hardcoding that behaviour.

```
void SwapZIndex(View v1, View v2)
{
    Debug.Assert(v1.ZIndex != v2.ZIndex);
    int z = v2.ZIndex;
    v2.ZIndex = v1.ZIndex;
    v1.ZIndex = z;
}

// Swap the order of details_frame and comments_frame
SwapZIndex(details_frame,comments_frame);
```

If you want to keep the RaiseChild semantics you could write a helper function to set the raised View's ZIndex above the rest of the children.

For completeness, [RaiseChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.compatibility.layout.raisechild?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-controls-compatibility-layout-raisechild(microsoft-maui-controls-view)) is available in the [Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.compatibility.grid?view=net-maui-7.0). For long term I'd recommend switching over to the ZIndex.

Comment: I give 10 for details_frame and 5 for comments_frame as the ZIndex values, Is that values are okay? The UI is working fine with that values.

Comment: The numbers can be anything that makes you happy. Views with the higher valued ZIndex will be higher than Views with lower values: 10 will be on top of 5.